# How to receive a a custom header and send it's value in a curl?

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

We're facing a weird error and we're not sure why this is happening.

There's a js client running that needs to make a request to a PHP server. That server needs to fetch data from a remote location, then return it to the js client. Each server is in a different domain and we have configured cross origin headers.

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "X-Session-Token, x-session-token"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Session-Token, x-session-token, Content-Type, content-type"
```

We must receive a custom header `x-session-token` from JS and forward it to the remote location as a header. See below the code doing that. We've added `a` and `b` around the custom header for illustration purposes.

```
 function generateCheckoutURL() {
    $protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http');
    $permalinkString = $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


    $headers = getallheaders();     
    $xSessionToken = "a " . $headers["X-Session-Token"] . " b";
    // echo $headers['X-Session-Token'];exit(); //

    $nonce = UtilsStatic::createNonceWithBodyData();
    $curl = curl_init($this->apiURL . 'checkout?permalink=' . $permalinkString . '&nonce=2');

    $requestHeaders = [
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Authorization: ' . $this->apiAuth,
      'X-Session-Token: ' . $xSessionToken


    ];

    // print_r($requestHeaders);exit();

    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeaders);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);    
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $bodyData);

    $checkout = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));

    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);

    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    http_response_code($httpcode);

    return $checkout;
  }
```

Here's the log from the remote server displaying the received value. It's not receiving the part of the string that is supposed to have the custom header.

```
CheckoutResource - X-Session-Token [a  b]
```

Now what's really weird is that if we just set a string there instead of loading the custom header from `getallheaders` we just set it to a specific value, it works as expected. I've tried to use other custom headers as well and the same problem happens, regardless of the header name.

If it matters, we have full control over the remote server that's meant to process the header and the php scripts are served with apache.

*Edit*

As requested, response from `getAllHeaders`. I can print the header and use it as a string, it's just not sent in curl.

```
Array
(
    [Host] => local.menus.com
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Content-Length] => 504
    [Pragma] => no-cache
    [Cache-Control] => no-cache
    [X-Session-Token] => o154fl5qt7ifqf67r3novits1q
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36
    [Content-type] => application/json
    [Accept] => */*
    [Origin] => http://localhost:8282
    [Referer] => http://localhost:8282/
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-BR;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7
)
```

Comment: Make a debug output of the array `getallheaders` returns, to see what is _actually_ contained in it.

Comment: can we see the code behind `getallheaders()`

Comment: @DhavalPurohit that is core PHP, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Comment: then may be it is in small case `x-session-token`

Comment: @misorude Thanks i didn't know it's a php function.

Comment: Added headers as requested.